# How to use hyphens in view file names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

Suppose I've got a controller called `Blog`. Inside that controller is an action called `programmingfordummies`.

In my routes would be

```
get 'blog/programmingfordummies'
```

For SEO purposes, I would like the URL to read `xyz.com/blog/programming-for-dummies`

What I've done already is:

```
  get 'blog/programmingfordummies'
  get '/blog/programming-for-dummies', to: 'blog#programmingfordummies'
```

When I run `rake routes`, they're both there, but only the first one has a path I can reference.

Is this possible? If so, then how so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved like so:

```
get '/blog/programming-for-dummies', 
    to: 'blog#programmingfordummies', 
    as: 'blog_programmingfordummies'
```

Can be referenced in the view as:

```
blog_programmingfordummies_path
```